# Filter by dateTime interval in SQLAlchemy the following query

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a flask API that is connected to a Postgres database, i
am trying to create a route that will give me the historic data from the database so that i can receive a json to display on the frontend (ReactJS) as a chart.

Now,I have the following query that runs sucessfully on pgAdmin :

```
SELECT humidity, temperature, "waterpumpState", "dateTime" from public."systemInformation"  where "systemInformation"."dateTime" > current_date - interval '7 days'
```

I have this database created model with SQLAlchemy:

```py
class statusInformation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'systemInformation'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    humidity = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    temperature = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    waterpumpState = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    clientOverride = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    humidityLevelSetting = db.Column((db.String(250)))
    dateTime = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, server_default=db.func.current_timestamp(), nullable=False)
```

From this table, i want to extract only humidity, temperature and dateTime using SQLAlchemy query.

I want to get all the entries that are no older than 7 days from this moment so that i can map them to a JSON that gets displayed when i call this route, with the response i want to create a ReactJS chart that shows the level of humidity and temperature over the 7 days.

This is what i've tried to do with SQLAlchemy in python using datetime:

```py
def get_historic_data():
        now = datetime.now()
        seven_days_ago = now - timedelta(days=7)
        historicData = statusInformation.query.filter(statusInformation.dateTime >= seven_days_ago)
        return statusInformation.historyDetailedInformationJson(historicData)
```

The historyDetailedInformationJson is just a template of the JSON that should get back to me and it looks like this:

```py
   def historyDetailedInformationJson(self):
        return{
            'humidity':self.humidity,
            'temperature':self.temperature,
            'waterpumpState':self.waterpumpState,
            'dateTime':self.dateTime
        }
```

This is what i got when i tried to print the result from get_historic_data :

```
SELECT "systemInformation".id AS "systemInformation_id", "systemInformation".emInformation".temperature AS "systemInformation_temperature", "systemInformaterpumpState", "systemInformation"."clientOverride" AS "systemInformation_clilSetting" AS "systemInformation_humidityLevelSetting", "systemInformation"."d
FROM "systemInformation"
WHERE "systemInformation"."dateTime" >= %(dateTime_1)s
```

If anyone can help me clarify the problem, I would greatly appreciate it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`statusInformation.query.filter(statusInformation.dateTime >= seven_days_ago)` will result in a [`Query` object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query), you can incrementally build up a query with filters etc. but you need to specify the form the results will take to actually execute a query.

E.g. (assuming `statusInformation` is a SQLAlchemy ORM Model) if `historicData` is your query object, then `historicData.all()` will return the rows the query returns as a list of objects. If you only expect one result, `historicData.one()` will return a single object and raise an exception if there was actually more than one row in the results of the query.

If you check the [query docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query) there are other methods which resolve queries in other ways (e.g. `one_or_none()`, `count()`).

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I have added .all() at the end of my query since i want all the entries that are in the 7 days interval. But i don't know how to get that data and return / print it so that i can see the values or the format that it comes in. When i try to return the value i get :  `TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable` .

Comment: Ok cool - could you add some more context to the post? Seeing what `statusInformation` is and what you're trying to do with `.all()` now would be helpful

Comment: I have updated the context but i will write here as well. statusInformation is my table, that contains humidity, temperature, waterpumpState and dateTime. I want to create a chart in React so that i can display the humidity and temperature over a 7 days period. So, i want to get all the rows that are under 7 days old, map the response from the query to a json and finally send it as a response to a route of the api. What i have trouble with is getting the data from the rows, since i might've write the query wrong and map it to a json. Hopefully it is clear enough now.

Comment: Assuming `historyDetailedInformationJson` is a method on `statusInformation`, could you try:
`return [status_info.historyDetailedInformationJson() for status_info in  statusInformation.query.filter(statusInformation.dateTime >= seven_days_ago).all()]`
which I would expect to return a list of the dicts containing the attributes you want

Comment: I have tried with the default historyDetailedJson and i get this : `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. I have also tried modifying the json format so that i would have it defined like this: `def historyDetailedInformationJson(self):
        return{ [
                  {
                    'humidity':self.humidity,
                    'temperature':self.temperature,
                    'waterpumpState':self.waterpumpState,
                    'dateTime':self.dateTime
                  }
                ]
        }` and it still doesn't work telling me that 'dict' is unhashable